# R order columns in a two-way table based on Row values

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to order the columns within a two-way table I have created based upon row values.
I have saved the two-way table as a table, thus putting it into a dataframe (I am using R).
The below code should create a two-way table based on the built-in Iris data.

In the example I have given, see the attached picture, if you ordered the columns based upon the first row the column order should be setosa, virginica, Versicolor.
The second row would order the columns virginica, Versicolor, Setosa.
The third row would order the columns as Versicolor, virginica, setosa.
so far the only solution I have is `WinEUref19[,order(WinEUref19[nrow(WinEUref19),])]` but this can only do the last row, is it possible to order the columns by the second or first row?

Replciable code:

```
Data <- iris
Data $ var2 <- iris $ Species
Data $ var2 <- sample(Data $ var2)
Df <-table(Data $ var2, iris $ Species)
rownames(Df) <- c("Row one","Row two", "Row three")
Df

            setosa versicolor virginica
  Row one       14         19        17
  Row two       22         15        13
  Row three     14         16        20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can order by any row. Just compute the order of the values and set the resulting vector as a selection criterion for the columns.

```
> Df[,order(Df[1,])]
           
            setosa versicolor virginica
  Row one       15         17        18
  Row two       18         15        17
  Row three     17         18        15

> Df[,order(Df[2,])]
           
            versicolor virginica setosa
  Row one           17        18     15
  Row two           15        17     18
  Row three         18        15     17

> Df[,order(Df[3,])]
           
            virginica setosa versicolor
  Row one          18     15         17
  Row two          17     18         15
  Row three        15     17         18
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have the answer already. you can order the table by the first row like this:

`Df[,order(Df[1,])]`

By the second row like this:

`Df[,order(Df[2,])]`

and so on.